# How to create a custom login form

Tags: 8, forms

I need to know please any suggestion about how to create a custom login form for another type of users in drupal 8 , I have now `/user/login` is for administrator, but I need to add `/account/login` it's different for the first one and it's for a normal user and this form should use the functionnalities of Drupal 8.

Comment: Isn't the user login form provided as a block? And you could create a page, put that block there and customize it?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following:

1. Add your new route to `[MODULE].routing.yml`

```
[MODULE].login:
  path: '/account/login'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\[MODULE]\Form\CustomUserLoginForm'
    _title: 'Log in'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'FALSE'
  options:
    _maintenance_access: TRUE
```

2. Create `CustomUserLoginForm` inside *[MODULE]/src/Form/* folder like the following:

```
namespace Drupal\[MODULE]\Form;

use Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm;

class CustomUserLoginForm extends UserLoginForm{

}
```

3. Flush the cache.
   it works but i don't know if it's the best approach.

Comment: Whats the difference though? It won't change any of the experience or routes after this user logs in. If its simply to change their login destination for example, there is a module that will do that. I don't think the question really has enough detail as to the purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I already made that, my question is I want to know the core of the Login() function , like the process of the login in drupal 8 to make a login with the same approach of drupal 8

Comment: If you want to know the login mechanism of the the process login take a look at UserLoginForm Class [Here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Form%21UserLoginForm.php/class/UserLoginForm/8.2.x)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution : 
 1. add your roote to `routing.yml`

```
myModule.account:

  path: /account/login

  defaults:

    _title: 'Connect'

    _controller: 

'\Drupal\myModule\Controller\AccountController::Login'
```

2. Add your Controller file in 
    `myModule/src/Controller/AccountController.php`

```
namespace Drupal\myModule\Controller;



use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;



class AccountController extends ControllerBase

{

public function Login(){

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment asmaa, but I already made that, my question is I want to know the core of the Login() function , like the process of the login in drupal 8 , to make a login with the same approach of drupal 8